# Simple? question about how to clearInterval() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

My

```
 setInterval('name(var)',6000);
```

won't clear with:

```
clearInterval('name(var)');
```

or with:

```
clearInterval('name(var)');
```

why?

Comment: Pass functions to setInterval, not strings to be evaled. Passing a string is ugly and inefficient at best and does horrible things to scope at worst.

Comment: i was getting name setInterval error (on firebu) if not..) can you please write the correct syntax for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setInterval` returns a handle of the interval, so you do it like this:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){ name(var) }, 6000);
clearInterval(myInterval);
```

Note: Notice how I used a anonymous function instead of a string too.

Answer (score 3):

You need to store the returned intervalID and pass it to clearInterval later.

```
var intervalID = setInterval('name(var)',6000);
clearInterval(intervalID);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass in the interval id returned from setInterval
ex:

```
var id = setInterval('name(var)', 2000);
clearInterval(id);
```

More information here.
http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
var id = setInterval('name(var)',6000);
clearInterval(id);
```